# how to catch api resonse data in react js

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

i have one project in spring boot where i have created one API login.where i am sending user name and password with this API .if data is present in database it is returning login successfully if not then it is returning login fail.in react i have to text filed and i am storing that data.now i want to call login API in react with saved text field value and if login successfully then i want to save that response or that returned value in react it may be login successfully or all user details or show that response in react.please anyone help

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried ?

Comment: Sure,It is Service Class                                                                                                                       public UserEntity login(LoginDto loginDto) {
  UserEntity entityClass = repositoryClass.findOneByUserIdIgnoreCaseAndPassword(loginDto.getUserId(),loginDto.getPassword());
  System.out.println(entityClass);
  if(entityClass==null) {

   return null;
  }

  return entityClass;
 }

Comment: And it is my Api Result

Comment: Hibernate: select userentity0_.id as id1_0_, userentity0_.full_name as full_nam2_0_, userentity0_.password as password3_0_, userentity0_.user_id as user_id4_0_ from todo_app userentity0_ where upper(userentity0_.user_id)=upper(?) and userentity0_.password=?
UserEntity(id=29, fullName=abcd, userId=abcd123, password=123456)

Comment: i want to show username on my Reactjs project if user is available in database.

Comment: i am trying this thing in react

Comment: fetch("http://localhost:8083/api/auth/login",{
        method : "POST",
        headers : {"Content-type" : "application/json"},
        body : JSON.stringify(student)
      }).then((response)=>response.json())
      .then((responseJson)=>setReturnValue(responseJson.results));
      console.log(returnvalue);

Answer (score 0):

Use Error handling function

```
try{
//Call your API here
}
catch(){
//Error handles here
}
finally{
//Executes anyway
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to save your response in state then show it on frontend

```
import axios from 'axios';
const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState([]);
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {

        const requestBody = {
            emailAddress: email,
            password: password,
        }

        axios.post(`${config.url.API_URL}${BASE_URL.Auth_BASE_URL}/login`, requestBody)
            .then(response => {
                if (response) {
                    setLoginData(response);
                    console.log("Login success");

                } else {
                    console.error("Login fail");
                }

            }).catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
        });
    } catch (err) {

        console.log(err);
    }
}
```